# Outline stroke from path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, pathfinder

I've made a path in Illustrator which I need to be outlined.
Quickest way to do this is with *Outline Stroke*, but then you'll get this united shape (see object in the middle below).

Is there a way to outline a path in a *Devide*-like way?

I want the object to be like the first cross, instead of the second cross I'm getting with *Outline Stroke*.

I want the object to be devided so I can easily remove imperfections.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Object > Flatten Transparency` and move the **slider all the way to the right**. Even though there maybe no transparency, for some reason (which I can't explain) this command expands the stroke in a different manner.

[image]

This is somewhat dependent upon the *version* of Illustrator you maybe using. The commands have a nasty tendency to be slightly different based on the Illustrator version. For example, CS6 won't leave that centerline, when flattening transparency or Expanding, like CC does.

Comment: I'm getting the same result with Expand. All elements are united into a single shape - only with the initial path still showing within.

Comment: @Martijn I was looking at the cross with Expand (multiple paths). See my updated answer for a single path option.