# Merging colors in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I have this color wheel I made that I want to use to pick colors from. The concentric circles inside are made with an increasingly transparent white. My issue is that if I use the eyedropper on it, it samples the transparent white instead of the overall color. I would prefer not to resort to rasterizing the image. Is there a way I can merge the white transparency with the color under to have a converted color?

[image]

Comment: Related:  

[What is Transparency Flattening](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/45869/63979/),   

[Outline stroke from path in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/77079/63979)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by *Flattening Transparency*.

1. You can select all (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>**A**</kbd>)
2. Go to *Object > Flatten Transparency* (I would select the highest quality for *Vectors* 100%)
3. Then ungroup all the items (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**G**</kbd>)

This will make all the paths as the color that they appear, without transparency etc.

<sub>**Note** that if the transparent white circles are a gradient, that may create many many shapes - you may want to use one solid color.</sub>

---

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge or average colors and transparencies on different layers to create 1 color, I believe. You can flatten your color wheel to sample each tint but this will leave you with an un-editable image similar to if you rasterized it.

It is possible to create even and precise grades of tints by adjusting values numerically. Starting with your source color you can generate tints by upping the B value (Brightness? The S value also adjusts the tint or transparency):

[image]

Also instead of overlaying a white transparency you can adjust the Opacity of your color directly. This will allow you to set your stops evenly:

[image]